# What is the optimal temperature for PLA+?

Tags: creality-ender-3, temperature, pla+

I'm planning on switching to using PLA+ and am slicing a few models, I'm wondering what the typical optimal temperature for PLA+ is with the Ender 3.

Comment: AFAIK every manufacturer has some suggested temperatures for their products. Beside of that the temperature you are printing with depends on your local setup. So it is a good idea to make some testprints with new filament. Print a temp tower and see which temparture performs best for yours.

Comment: There are multiple formulations for PLA+ and you have not specified a manufacturer, so we don't have enough information to give a specific answer that isn't a guess.

Comment: [What is PLA+? How is it different from PLA?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4982/what-is-pla-how-is-it-different-from-pla)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the filament spool will have a range of temperatures for the best nozzle temperatures and bed temperatures to use.  To answer your quesstion there are several considerations.

1. Not all PLA's are the same and that is probably even more so with PLA+.  That is where the temperatures written on the spool come in handy.
2. Optimum temperatures will vary for different printers.
3. Optimum temperatures will vary depending on the print job: large versus small; thick versus thin; short verses long; etc.
4. Optimum temperature will vary depending on print speed, as well as enclosure or lack of, and air circulating through enclosure with fans.

You may need to tweak settings to get the optimum print.

Comment: Also note that filament vendor's temperature ranges are usually specified assuming you're printing at snail speed. If you'll be going significantly faster you probably need to increase them. This isn't just compensation for an underpowered hotend not keeping up (which can be an issue) but for the heat that needs to be transferred to the previous layer to get the new one to bond to it, which can be reached at low speeds just by having the nozzle dwell in the vicinity for a long time but needs a hot nozzle at high speeds.

Comment: @R. I thought about this with 3, but it really belongs separate thus 4.